# Makefile: not detecting that target executable has already been built (gnu make)

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

### Introduction

I have a simple project in plain C, which I am building with a handwritten Makefile and gcc (in linux).

It works (almost) perfectly fine, but there is a small issue: It doesn't detect that the target has already been built.

### Makefile + Project Structure

It consists of a single `.c` and `.h` file, which compiles to an executable.

```
comms_test    <-- resulting executable 
comms_test.c  
comms_test.h  
comms_test.o
```

My makefile looks like this:

```
PROJ := comms_test

CSRCS = $(PROJ).c

CC := cc
LD := gcc

INCLUDES := \
        -I. 

LDFLAGS = 

CPPFLAGS = 

CFLAGS := \
      -O0 \
      -Wpedantic


OBJS += $(CSRCS:%.c=%.o)


.PHONY: all
all: options $(PROJ)

.PHONY: options 
options: 
    @echo $(PROJ) build options:
    @echo "CC           = $(CC)"
    @echo "CFLAGS       = $(CFLAGS)"
    @echo "CPPFLAGS     = $(CPPFLAGS)"
    @echo "INCLUDES     = $(INCLUDES)"
    @echo "LDFLAGS      = $(LDFLAGS)"

%.o: %.c
    ${CC} ${CPPFLAGS} ${CFLAGS} ${INCLUDES} -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: ${PROJ}
${PROJ}: ${OBJS}
    ${LD} -o $@ ${OBJS} ${LDFLAGS}

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf ${OBJS} ${PROJ}

.PHONY: echo
echo:
    @echo ${CSRCS}
    @echo ${OBJS}

.PHONY: test
```

To build, I just call `make` or (to skip the CC options printout) `make comms_test`. `make clean` etc pp works too just fine. The `options` target is a holdover from other projects where I suppress the printing of the compiler flags on each single .c file (might be dozens), so I just print them once at the top for better readability.

### The Issue

The linking step doesn't "understand" that the target executable has already been built. When I call `make comms_test`, it always runs `gcc -o comms_test comms_test.o`, even though the resulting executable already exists, and the input .o file has not changed.

How can I fix this issue? I am clearly writing my make rule for that incorrectly. Any suggestion?

---

### EDIT:

I just remembered, If I remove the `.PHONY: ${PROJ}` it won't relink the executable, but it still will do the `options`/`all` target. What I want, is to detect that the executable already exists, and then decide that the requirements for the `options` target are already satisfied. If nothing was actually compiled/linked, I also do NOT want the options output, but no output (or "nothing to be done"), otherwise this is a bit confusing.

Comment: Hint: why do you have `.PHONY: ${PROJ}`?  What effect do you think that has?

Comment: yes, i just realized that while pressing "send", that it will suppress the check if a file named `${PROJ}` already exists. but it doesnt fix that it will still do the `options` target, which I do not understand.

Comment: `options` is phony as well, and `all: options $(PROJ)` explicitly tells make to build the target `options` seperately (and independently) from `$(PROJ)`. So it gets made every time.

Comment: Hm -- how do I decouple these two then? Is there a way to run `options` only wenn something is actually built? One way would be to completely separate these and always do `make options && make` but that is not what I want...

Comment: The default goal is `all` (not because of its name that is not special, but because it is the first target). If you don't want `options` to be done when you `make` (or, as it is the default, `make all`), then don't declare it as a prerequisite of `all`. Then, if you want to see the build options, just `make options`. And if you want to see them when your project is rebuilt simply add `$(MAKE) options` to the `${PROJ}: ${OBJS}` recipe.

Comment: Note: because of target-specific variable values it would be safer to completely remove tour `options` target and add its recipe to that of `${PROJ}: ${OBJS}`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, the OP seems to want the options printed first, before anything else is done (but only if there is anything else *to* be done).  For that, it is not, in general, sufficient to print the options from the recipe for the executable, because some or all of its prerequisites may be built before the options are printed by the executable's recipe.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh! I did not understand that, thanks. If this is really what they want it is doable but not that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking a target `.PHONY` instructs (GNU) `make` to consider that target out of date at the beginning of every run, regardless of the existence or timestamp of any same-named file.  As discussed in comments and your self-answer, that's why you are observing program `comms_test` being re-linked unnecessarily (but not `comms_test.o` being re-compiled unnecessarily).

That's also part of why you are seeing the `options` output whenever you `make` or `make all` but not when you `make comms_test`.  The `options` target is marked `.PHONY` (as it should be), **and it is designated a prerequisite of the the default target, `all`**.  Thus, the recipe for `options` will run whenever you build `all`, whether explicitly or as the default target.

> What I want, is to detect that the executable already exists, and then decide that the requirements for the options target are already satisfied. If nothing was actually compiled/linked, I also do NOT want the options output, but no output (or "nothing to be done"), otherwise this is a bit confusing.

A *bona fide* file that you want `make` to build should never be marked `.PHONY`.  A target that does not correspond to an actual file to build should be marked `.PHONY`, but that just protects against misbehavior in the event that a corresponding file is created by some other means.  If you have behavior that you want to be executed only in the event that a given target is built on a given run, *before* that target itself is built, then that behavior should be triggered from the recipe for that target.  If you make it a prerequisite of the target then that will force the target to be rebuilt on every run, because the phony target is always initially out of date.

To trigger behavior from a recipe, you need to take control of the recipe -- that is, provide your own rule.  You cannot amend the recipe of an existing rule, only replace the whole rule with a different one.

But there's another problem: behavior exercised by a rule's recipe happens *after* all the rule's prerequisites are brought up to date.  You want the options to be evaluated / printed before anything is built if they are printed at all.  You may be able to make that work in this case, by building the executable directly from the C sources, but inasmuch as you complain about unnecessary *linking* of object files, that does not seem to be your actual case.

> The options target is a holdover from other projects where I suppress the printing of the compiler flags on each single .c file (might be dozens), so I just print them once at the top for better readability.

In the general case, you do need to control this in the recipes for all the contributing `.o` files (in addition to in the recipe for the executable).  Typically, however, this would be accomplished by providing your own implicit rule covering all the `.o` files, instead of writing a separate rule for every one.  You can also use a sub-`make` to perform the conditional logic for you.  Maybe something like this:

```
# ...

TS_FILE = build_ts

.PHONY: all

all:
    rm -f $(TS_FILE)
    $(MAKE) $(PROJ)

$(PROJ): $(OBJS)
    flock $(TS_FILE) $(MAKE) options
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^

%.o: %.c
    flock $(TS_FILE) $(MAKE) options
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) $<

# Not .PHONY; produces an actual file
options: $(TS_FILE)
    @echo $(PROJ) build options: | tee $@
    @echo "CC           = $(CC)" | tee -a $@
    @echo "CFLAGS       = $(CFLAGS)"  | tee -a $@
    @echo "CPPFLAGS     = $(CPPFLAGS)"  | tee -a $@
    @echo "INCLUDES     = $(INCLUDES)"  | tee -a $@
    @echo "LDFLAGS      = $(LDFLAGS)"  | tee -a $@
```

**Explanation:**

- The `all` target removes any pre-existing timestamp file, then uses a sub-`make` to build the executable.  This gets the timestamp file removed before anything else is done, even with parallel `make`.
- The `options` target is an ordinary target, producing a file a transcript of the options in addition to displaying them in the output.  Because it has the timestamp file as a prerequisite (and that is not `.PHONY` either), `make` will run the recipe only if the options transcript does not already exist or is older than the timestamp file.
- The recipe for linking the executable and the pattern rule by which all the `.o` files are built each use a sub-`make` to build the `options` target.  But that leaves open the possibility that in a parallel `make`, the options would be printed more than once.  To prevent that, the sub-`make` is gated by `flock`ing the timestamp file, which both causes it to be created if it does not already exist, and serializes all the `make options` executions, so that only the first can find `options` out of date.
- No rule for `$(TS_FILE)` is needed or wanted.

**Additional notes:**

- If you build the executable or any of the object files explicitly then you might or might not get the options printed, depending on whether the timestamp and options files from a previous build are still present.
- If your filesystem has low timestamp resolution then you might see the options printed more than once on a given run.
- Overall, **it would be much easier and more reliable to just print the options first on every run (or every build of the `all` target), regardless of whether anything else is to be done**.  You said that's not what you want, but it's what I would do in the unlikely event that I did anything at all of this sort.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks! For the workaround of suppressing the printout, the other answer below does the trick, but this explanation is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
define OPTIONS
    @echo $(PROJ) build options:
    @echo "CC           = $(CC)"
    @echo "CFLAGS       = $(CFLAGS)"
    @echo "CPPFLAGS     = $(CPPFLAGS)"
    @echo "INCLUDES     = $(INCLUDES)"
    @echo "LDFLAGS      = $(LDFLAGS)"
    $(eval OPTIONS=)
endef

define COMPILE
    $(OPTIONS)
    ${CC} ${CPPFLAGS} ${CFLAGS} ${INCLUDES} -c $< -o $@
endef

define LINK
    $(OPTIONS)
    ${LD} -o $@ ${OBJS} ${LDFLAGS}
endef

...

.PHONY: all
all: $(PROJ)

%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE)

...

${PROJ}: ${OBJS}
    $(LINK)
```

The first time a compilation (`COMPILE`) or linking (`LINK`) is run the options are printed thanks to the `OPTIONS` macro and the `OPTIONS` macro is redefined as empty string, such that on the next compilation/linking nothing is printed.

Comment: Very nice, the `define OPTIONS` and then in recipe body an `$(OPTIONS)` is a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to G.M. for pointing me in the right direction, it was the `.PHONY ${PROJ}` line. That does not solve the other problem of it printing always the `options` output, but that should probably be posed as a separate question. Marking as solved